# Custom field to display Confluence pages

Tags: groovy, jira, confluence

I have Confluence pages for all our Vendors and Customers. I would like a JIRA Custom field that would allow the Helpdesk to select a vendor or customer when creating a ticket.

I have Script Fields installed and have created a new field. I know how to get to the script window via the Add-ons administration. I have tried piecing together some stuff from [this page](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SCRP/Scripts) on Bob Swift's site (love that guy) but haven't had any luck.

I would post the code I had but I deleted the field to start over and then got frustrated so decided to ask here.

Comment: your  requirement is you need a custom field that can capture all your vendors and customers  and you need that field in create issue screen right?

Comment: I need a drop-down that is populated with certain confluence pages